# Lottie Animation looks linear puppeteer-lottie

Tags: puppeteer, animación

He estado usando puppeteer-lottie para exportar animaciones de lottie a MP4 y todo está bien, solo noto que el video final parece como si la animación se hubiera linealizado o sea como que mas lenta, cuando en la animación original es  más dinámica y con mayor velocidad.

Alguien sabe cómo resolver esto?

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Listo, ya esta en español.